# Hibernate query to group by Date with all logintime

Tags: javascript, java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to show everylogin time on particular day .but i get everytime date and time. Like

```
result is:-
 date          logintime          
2016-03-31      2016-03-31 (time)
2016-03-31      2016-03-31 (time)
2016-03-31      2016-03-31 (time)

But I want:-

date               logintime 
2016-03-31         2016-03-31 (time)
                   2016-03-31 (time)
                   2016-03-31 (time)
```

USERDAO CLASS:

```
public List<LoginLog> UserHistory(User user){

    String sql="from LoginLog where user = :user";
    TypedQuery<LoginLog> query = em.createQuery(sql, LoginLog.class);
    query.setParameter("user", user);

    List<LoginLog> logs = query.getResultList();
    return logs;
}
```

DEFAULT_USER CLASS

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public LoginLog punchLoginTime(User user) {
    LoginLog log = new LoginLog();
    log.setLoginTime(new Date());
    log.setUser(user);
    loginLogDao.create(log);
    return log;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public LoginLog punchLogoutTime(User user) {
    LoginLog log = getOpenUserLoginLog(user);
    log.setLogoutTime(new Date());
    long diff=log.getLogoutTime().getTime()-log.getLoginTime().getTime();
    log.setTotalTime(diff);
    log = loginLogDao.update(log);
    return log;
}

@Override
public boolean hasUserStarted(User user) {
    LoginLog log = loginLogDao.getOpenLoginLog(user);

    if (log == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public LoginLog getOpenUserLoginLog(User user) {
    return loginLogDao.getOpenLoginLog(user);
}

@Override
public List<LoginLog> UserHistroy(User user) {
    return loginLogDao.UserHistory(user);
}
```

LOGIN_CONTROLLER CLASS

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userloginhistory", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public String loginHistory(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

    List<LoginLog> logs = userService.UserHistroy(TimesheetSecutiryUtil
            .getLoggedInUser(request.getSession()));
    model.addAttribute("loginList", logs);
    return "userloginhistory";

}
```

This is Jsp.As I am new to this can anyone please tell me how can i do it?(either by hibernate query or at jsp level and how?) Thank you

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <td>Login Id</td>
       <td>Login Time</td>
       <td>Logout Time</td>
       <td>Total Time(in Minutes)</td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
<%
    List<LoginLog> log = (List<LoginLog>)request.getAttribute("loginList");
    if(log != null) {
       for(LoginLog login : log) {
 %>
<tr>
<td><%=login.getId()%></td>
<td><%=login.getLoginTime()%></td>
<td><%=login.getLogoutTime()%></td>
<td id="a<%=login.getId()%>">
     <span id="time<%=login.getId()%>"> 
     <%=login.getTotalTime()%></span> <script>
    var milliSeconds = document.getElementById("time<%=login.getId()%>").innerHTML;
    var c = convertTime(milliSeconds);
    document.getElementById("a<%=login.getId()%>").innerHTML = c;
  </script></td>
</tr>
<%
    }
 }
%>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) is an option you can easily convert `List<LoginLog>` to a [multi map](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and return [ImmutableListMultimap](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html) make it available to JSP file. For example,

```
private static class LoginLog {
    private Date loginTime;
    private Date logoutTime;

    LoginLog(Date loginTime) {
        this.loginTime = loginTime
    }
    // Getters and setters
}
```

and a grouping function,

```
private enum GroupBy implements Function<LoginLog, String> {
    LOGIN_TIME

    @Override
    String apply(LoginLog loginLog) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(loginLog.loginTime)
    }
}
```

and using [index](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index(java.util.Iterator,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) method

```
ImmutableListMultimap<String, LoginLog> listMultimap =  Multimaps.index(logs, GroupBy.LOGIN_TIME);
```

I don't think you can get an output similar to what is provided by multi map with pure HQL query and you would still need to get all the results as you're doing with

```
List<LoginLog> logs = query.getResultList();
```

Similar map data structure can be generated by looping through the `logs` list as well.